# name ___ is not defined - recursive fibonacci memoization

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, memoization

`NameError: name 'fib_cache' is not defined`

So I am trying to implement the fibonacci number sequence using memoization, but I keep getting this error in leetcode and I am not sure why. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
class Solution:
    
    fib_cache = {}
        
    def fib(self, n: int) -> int:
        
        value;
        
        if n <=1:
            value = n;
        elif n>2:
            value = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
            
        fib_cache[n] = value
        return value
```

Comment: Beside the point, but get rid of the semicolons. They're pointless in Python.

Comment: Replace the "fib_cache" in the function by "Solution.fib_cache".

Comment: What's with `value` on its own there? It's not defined at that point, and it wouldn't do anything anyway.

Comment: Curious what is supposed to happen when `n == 2`?

Comment: `fib_cache` is a class attribute, you need to use `Solution.fib_cache`

Comment: I think `class Solution:` is a LeetCode convention that they started using a few months ago.

Comment: The recursive calls to `fib()` are also going to raise `NameError`s. Have you learned classes already? Do you know what class/instance attributes are? If you have, why do *you* think the problem is occurring? If you haven't, you probably should before using LeetCode, cause it seems like their whole testing model relies on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed some lines in your code and now it works. And actually you were not using memoization in your code so I fixed this ,too.

```
class Solution:
    
    fib_cache = {}
        
    def fib(self, n: int) -> int:
        
        value = 0  # You don't need this line

        if n in Solution.fib_cache:  # this adds the memoziation idea
            return Solution.fib_cache[n]

        if n <=1:
            value = n
        elif n>=2:   # <==== Fixed this line
            value = self.fib(n-1) + self.fib(n-2)   # <==== Fixed this line
            
        Solution.fib_cache[n] = value  # <==== Fixed this line
        return value

s = Solution()   # You don't need these 2 lines in leetcode
print(s.fib(5))   #  I wrote them for testing
```

Output: 5